# Partition table broken, can't access data

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have this issues, it's seems like the partition table is broken, is there a posible to restero it or to recover data from all the hdd.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next stop, TestDisk:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

This is one of the go-to tools for partition recovery.

Comment: I try with TestDisk and the image below was the result.

Comment: Uh, one other thing - as the error message states, make sure e2fsprogs is installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @djvs, the e2fsprogs is in the newest version.